# Can we add keyboard shortcuts in ARC app

Tags: google-chrome-arc

How can we add keyboard shortcuts in Google Chrome ARC app? As ARC apps now work on desktop Chrome browser, it is a must to have for desktop clients.

Answer (score 1):

Try using android's [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html) to catch [KeyEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), or https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html as a reference.

If you want to handle keyboard events outside of a editable control then using a [KeyEvent.callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html) is recommended.

I have not verified this ability, but merely assuming that ARC apps interact with the keyboard just like android apps do.